# Handle elements that have changing ids

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running the script to automate test cases and found that id's keep on changing. Below is my HTML code
Firebug for test drive:

```
<button class="G0036HC-b-a G0036HC-b-o G0036HC-b-g" id="gwt-uid-470" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-470" role="button" type="button"><div class="G0036HC-b-j">Click to continue</div></button>
```

Inspector:

```
<button class="G0036HC-b-a G0036HC-b-o G0036HC-b-g" id="gwt-uid-320" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-320" role="button" type="button"><div class="G0036HC-b-j">Click to continue</div></button>
```

Only id's changes.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firebug:<button class="G0036HC-b-a G0036HC-b-o G0036HC-b-g" id="gwt-uid-320" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-320" role="button" type="button"><div class="G0036HC-b-j">Click to continue</div></button>

Comment: Inspector:<button class="G0036HC-b-a G0036HC-b-o G0036HC-b-g" id="gwt-uid-470" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-470" role="button" type="button"><div class="G0036HC-b-j">lick to continue</div></button>

Comment: is there a public url where we can check the whole DOM. It seems with the help of parent or sibling elements we should be able to locate element.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element by `xpath` and check that `id` attribute *starts with `gwt-uid-`*:

```
//button[starts-with(@id, "gwt-uid-")]
```

Comment: Tried , but doesn't work since all the buttons present in that page starts with id "gwt-uid-"

Comment: @SukeshBolar okay, but from the question, it is unclear which button do you need and how it differs from others.

Comment: The above two HTML codes are of two separate buttons. Their id="gwt-uid-320" is dynamic. Only the last 3 digits changes dynamically. Could you please help me out in fixing this issue?

Comment: @SukeshBolar okay, I would be glad to help, but need a clear picture. Do you need to click both buttons?

Comment: so tell us which one!

Comment: @alecxe Can you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642148/there-is-error-invalid-locator-values-passed-in-in-case-we-use-find-element-in/28643620#28643620)

Answer (score 1):

Besides, the answer @alecxe suggested I would also suggest you to try with text based `xpath` search. I often faced issue with wait so also suggest to use `explicit` wait this.

```
// //div[.='Click to continue']/..
By byXpath = By.xpath("//div[.='Click to continue']");

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath));
//    myDynamicElement.click();
```

Comment: I did a good job making my nickname too complicated to repeat correctly :D

Comment: O.o @alecxe That's really funny

Comment: @saifur still element not detected :(

Comment: @SukeshBolar what's the exception?

Comment: @Saifur Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. Tried waiting for that element.

Comment: @SukeshBolar Can you provide more `html` in that case?

Comment: @SukeshBolar Actually my bad. See corrected `xpath`

Comment: @SukeshBolar please check whether the element is under a frame / iframe or a modal dialog.

Comment: What if the UI is multilanguage?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following observations, the below code should work fine.

- All the buttons on the page are prefixed with *gwt-uid-* with changing number suffix
- If the buttons on the page have a unique text then use

By.xpath("//button/div[text()='Click to continue']")

- If there are multiple buttons with same text then use indexes. eg. two close buttons with same text then use,

By.xpath("(//button/div[text()='Close'])[2]")    # for the 2nd occurence, mind that selenium is not zero indexed

Answer (score 0):

use **following**...
//input[@id=’’]/following::input[1]

You can use **preceding** in the same way to identify the child node