# There is error "Invalid locator values passed in" in case we use find_element instead of find_element_by

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python-Webdriver to automate a "click" action. Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSelectorException


LOGIN_BUTTON = (By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class,"aui-nav-link login-link")]')
NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://bbc.co.uk/")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(NEWS_OPTION)
myDynamicElement.click()
```

The console generates an exception as below

```
    raise InvalidSelectorException("Invalid locator values passed in")
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Invalid locator values passed in
```

But, if I change the line

> "myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(NEWS_OPTION) "

to

> "myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id('blq-nav-news') "

, there is no exception and the script works as expected.

I figured out the root cause is we don't use

> find_element_by_*

. So I'd like to know this is limitation on Python-Webdriver ? whether we have a solution to fix my issue without changing my code as I did.

Comment: never worked in python but just a general asking find_element as seen in docs takes 2 parameters, passing one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html), you can use either `find_element_by_*` shortcuts, or `find_element()` and `find_elements()` "private" methods directly:

> Apart from the public methods given above, there are two private
>   methods which might be useful with locators in page objects. These are
>   the two private methods: find_element and find_elements.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>
> driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
> driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
> ```

But, in your case, instead of passing 2 parameters to `find_element()`, you are passing a single one - a `tuple` `NEWS_OPTION`. You just need to unpack the tuple into positional arguments:

```
NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news')
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(*NEWS_OPTION)
```

Or, just as an alternative, you could use keyword arguments also:

```
NEWS_OPTION = {'by': By.ID, 'value': 'blq-nav-news'}
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(**NEWS_OPTION)
```

---

And, also, whenever you have any doubts how things should work, just dig up the source code and clarify it for yourself. In this case, see how `find_element_by_id()` method is [actually implemented](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#199):

```
def find_element_by_id(self, id_):
    """Finds an element by id.

    :Args:
     - id\_ - The id of the element to be found.

    :Usage:
        driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
    """
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe for chiming in. I guess `NEWS_OPTION = {'by': By.ID, 'value': 'blq-nav-news'}
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(**NEWS_OPTION)` we had been looking for

Comment: @alecxe: it's very detailed explanation. As your suggestion, reading source code to find out the root cause, but I'm news on Python, then maybe it's difficult to understand. From the source code "return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)", how you can know where my issue is ? would you like to take time to instruct me ?

Comment: @askandconcern thank you, I've just pointed out that there is a `find_element()` call inside the `find_element_by_id()` method. As you can see, it is called with `by` and `value` arguments.

Comment: @alecxe: I guess that the return value is 2 arguments (by, value), but my case is one because mine is tuple. So, I need to unpack it. - is it right ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [api doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) private method `find_elements` and `find_element` takes two `parameters` each and you are passing one which is obviously wrong.

And,

> myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(NEWS_OPTION)

and

> myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id('blq-nav-news')

are NOT same. `driver.find_element_by_id` takes one parameter and thus this work and `find_element` takes two so that fails.

So, literally you should be using

```
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(By.ID,'blq-nav-news')
```

**EDIT**

`NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news')` will return you `('id', 'blq-nav-news')` whereas `find_element()` expects the first parameter to be the implementation of `By` class mechanism to locate the element not simply a string.

A direct call of `NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news')` has returned me a `tuple` and the attribute of `By.ID` which is `'id'`
A simple print out of `NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news')` provided me

> `('id', 'blq-nav-news')`

And, here is the source of `By` class

```
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"

    @classmethod
    def is_valid(cls, by):
        for attr in dir(cls):
            if by == getattr(cls, attr):
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: @Saifur, as you mentioned "find_element" takes two arguments, but the NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blq-nav-news') also considered as two when we putting it to "find_element(NEWS_OPTION)"

Comment: @VivekSingh You are absolutely right. But I am little confused what you are asking here about encapsulation.

Comment: @Saifur my mistake even though i noticed methods i thought of it as fields so wrote encapsulation... :D

Comment: @Saifur, thank for your editing. In case, I want to use the NEWS_OPTION = (By.ID, 'blah-blah,,,,') as the "GO_BUTTON" at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/page-objects.html, how can I edit my code

Comment: I don't want to misdirect you. I am not very knowledgeable on `Python` but looking at the link you provided looks like it's using different class and calling the field directly and that seems correct. Let's wait for someone else to chime in.

Comment: I informed another person who would be able to answer this question. Let's wait for him

Comment: @Saifur thank you for the referral and your answer is actually correct and should be accepted, I think.