# If the field exists then check if it is readonly or not

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to check if the field exist, if this exist I need to make sure it is a read only field.

This is what I have tried, however i do not think it is a very efficient way to do:

```
         if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address2']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='address2' and @readonly='readonly']")
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city' and @readonly='readonly']")
        # country
        elif self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']"):
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']/../select[@disabled='disabled']")
```

I tried to use this method too but the problem is that it will not throw an error when is the field is present without being readonly:

```
def verifyReadOnly(self, driver):
        try: 
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' or @id='address' or @id='city' or @id='address2' and @readonly='readonly']")
        except NoSuchElementException: 
            pass

        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cf_2698238' and @readonly='']")
        except NoSuchElementException: 
            pass

        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='country']/../select[@disabled='disabled']")
        except NoSuchElementException: 
            pass
```

Comment: If your code works, but you need to improve it, you should ask your question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can try something like: `try: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' or @id='address' or @id='city' or @id='address2' and @readonly='readonly']") except NoSuchElementException: pass`

Comment: @Andersson, is it possible to add or inside and? Something like this: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' or @id='address' or @id='city' or @id='address2' and @readonly='readonly'] or @readonly=''] ")

Comment: also i would like to raise an exception if the the field is present but not readable. it should give an error

Comment: You will get an exception if predicate return `False`. As for your `XPath`, note that `readonly` is `boolean`, so `readonly` == `readonly="readonly"` == `readonly=""`. If you want to check if there is no `readonly` attribute you can use `not(@readonly)`

Comment: @Andersson, so that means i do not have to use @readonly='readonly' and @readonly='' seprately? just like i have it in my answer above?

Comment: if you want to check whether `readonly` attribute is present or not, just use `[@readonly]` or `[not(@readonly)]`. `@readonly=''` also checks if `readonly` **is present**

Comment: @Andersson, got it. so this will be correct right:   try: 
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='cname' or @id='address' or @id='city' or @id='address2' or @id='state' or @id='zip' or @id='cf_2698238' and @readonly]")
        except NoSuchElementException: 
            pass

Comment: Yes. This should work, but `id='cf_2698238'` might be dynamic...

Comment: @Andersson, no the id will remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `element.is_enabled()` to figure out if the element is readonly. If it's readonly, `is_enabled()` will return `false`. See [the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled).

When I write code that I will reuse, I write a function. In this case, I would write a function that takes in a locator parameter and then returns `true` if the element exists and `is_enabled()` is `false`. Then you would call this function for each element and assert that each return is `true`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28661040/2386774) should get you started, if you need help passing locators as parameters.