# Selenium Continue script if Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a problem, when I acces a website if want to check if the element is displayed and enabled. If that is the case I want to print something. If the element is not displayed and enabled I want to check for a new element, if that element is displayed if want to print something. I hope you get the point.

When visiting a website and the first IF statement is NOT detected / displayed it gives and error instead of going to the next If statement.

ERROR:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="errorLongContent"]
```

I already tried using try, expect and changed the if statement to elif.

I hope someone can help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Setup browser for
options = Options()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://agar.io")

#Xpaths
PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="play"]'
PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION = '//*[@id="errorLongContent"]'
TIMEOUT_XPATH1 = '//*[@id="errorTryAgain"]'


#checking for error
def mainfunction():
    while True:
        print("Starting")
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_displayed():
            print("Proxy denies connection")
            driver.quit()

        if driver.find_element_by_xpath(TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_displayed():
            print("Time out detected")
            driver.quit()

        if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_displayed():
            print("Agar.io server is loaded")
            break

        else:
            continue

mainfunction()
```

EDIT: Try and except

```
def mainfunction():
    while True:
        print("Starting")
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_displayed():
                print("Proxy denies connection")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            continue
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_displayed():
                print("Time out detected")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            continue

        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_displayed():
                print("Agar.io server is loaded")
                break
        except:
            continue
```

When I run this it, runs in an infinite loop printing only Starting...

Comment: what happened when trying with `try` and `except`? why it did not work?

Comment: @MagedSaeed I have edited my question with the code I used, When I run this it, it runs in an infinite loop printing only Starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `driver.find_element*.something()`, `driver.find_element*` will throw if the element is not found. That's what the issue is with your first code block so checking with `if` won't matter. You can get around this a couple ways.

1. `try-except`, which you already tried. The problem with your attempt is that apparently one or more of your locators are not working. That's why you get an infinite loop.
2. Use `.find_elements_*` (note the plural) and check for a non-empty list. BUT... this won't fix the bad locators issue, it's just an alternative to `try-catch`, etc.

   ```
   if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION))
       # do something
   ```

Other notes:

1. Don't use an XPath when you are just looking for an ID, e.g. replace

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="play"]')
   ```

   with

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_id('play')
   ```
2. `.is_enabled()` really is only useful for `INPUT` tags. On anything else, it pretty much returns `true` all the time.
3. `.is_enabled()` already assumes `.is_displayed()` so no need to check both.
4. Instead of using strings to store only the locator (and not the type), store the tuple and use it like `driver.find_element(tuple)`. It will make your code a lot cleaner and more flexible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28661040/2386774) for more info.

With this feedback, you can simplify your code to something more like the below. Assuming your locators are all good (and no `IFRAME`s), this should work.

```
#locators
PLAY_BUTTON = (By.ID, 'play')
PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION = (By.ID, 'errorLongContent')
TIMEOUT = (By.ID, 'errorTryAgain')

def mainfunction():
    print("Starting")
    while True:
        try:
            if driver.find_element(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_displayed():
                print("Proxy denies connection")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            continue

        try:
            if driver.find_element(TIMEOUT).is_displayed():
                print("Time out detected")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            continue

        try:
            if driver.find_element(PLAY_BUTTON).is_displayed():
                print("Agar.io server is loaded")
                break
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 3):

I placed your if statements inside a "try/except" statement and it runs without the error mentioned above.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Setup browser for
options = Options()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://agar.io")

#Xpaths
PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH = '//*[@id="play"]'
PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION = '//*[@id="errorLongContent"]'
TIMEOUT_XPATH1 = '//*[@id="errorTryAgain"]'


#checking for error
def mainfunction():
    while True:
        print("Starting")
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_displayed():
                print("Proxy denies connection")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_displayed():
                print("Time out detected")
                driver.quit()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_displayed():
                print("Agar.io server is loaded")
                break
        except:
            pass

        else:
            continue

mainfunction()
```

Comment: Sorry I should have read your question more carefully. In your except statement change "continue" to "pass".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking only for a specific button to load. What about this:

```
 while True:
    print("Starting")
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_displayed():
            print("Agar.io server is loaded")
            break
    except:
        print('button did not load yet! waiting for a second')
        time.wait(1)
        continue
```

Note that this will wait **forever** until the button arrives!!

Answer (score 2):

isDisplayed() exists to tell you whether the element, which has already been located,
is visible on the page; i.e. whether its width and height are greater than zero, it
isn't hidden by CSS, etc.  If the element is present on the page, but has style="display:
none;" then isDisplayed() will return false.

And if element is not present then it throw NoSuchElementException,So you cannot use if and else
Instead use try and expect.

```
def mainfunction():
    while True:
        print("Starting")
        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PROXY_DENIES_CONNECTION).is_displayed():
                print("Proxy denies connection")
                driver.quit()

            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    TIMEOUT_XPATH1).is_displayed():
                print("Time out detected")
                driver.quit()

            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_enabled() and driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    PLAY_BUTTON_XPATH).is_displayed():
                print("Agar.io server is loaded")
                break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
```

And as you have mentioned your code ran into an infinite loop that is happening because it's stuck inside the while loop(i.e never executing driver.quit() or break statement). 
As isDisplay throw an exception and then flow goes to the expect block which contain continue statement.