# Replace if/elif - with switch-case python with selenium(code simplification solutions)

Tags: python, selenium

--this question is not about fixing a problem, but about how to simplify existing code--I am working on Selenium with Python automation frame Work. Inside my Action() class i have several functions. 2 of them such as Click() and Send_keys()  have a lot of if/elif statements. Can someone help me out how this can be changed to switch-case logic?
Thanks

```
try:
    if locatorStrategy == 'id':  # return by ID
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'xp':  # return by XPATH
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'li':  # return by link text
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'na':  # return by name
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_name(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'cs':  # return by css
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'pa':  # return by partiL LINK TEXT
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'ta':  # return by tag name
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name(locator).click()

    elif locatorStrategy == 'cl':  # return by class name
        ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_class_name(locator).click()
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(e)
```

Comment: Don't do any of these. Instead of passing a string to indicate what type of locator it is, instead pass the locator itself. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642148/there-is-error-invalid-locator-values-passed-in-in-case-we-use-find-element-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is error "Invalid locator values passed in" in case we use find\_element instead of find\_element\_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642148/there-is-error-invalid-locator-values-passed-in-in-case-we-use-find-element-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
ele = {'id': self.driver.find_element_by_id,
       'xp'; self.driver.find_element_by_xpath,
       'li': self.driver.find_element_by_link_text,
       'na': self.driver.find_element_by_name,
       'cs': self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector,
       'pa': self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text,
       'ta': self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name,
       'cl': self.driver.find_element_by_class_name,
 }[locatorStrategy](locator).click()
```

Or instead of using two-letter codes, use the actual name of the method (e.g. `locatorStrategy = "find_element_by_id"`) and use:

```
ele = getattr(self.driver, locatorStrategy)(locator).click()
```

The `try/except` would be the same as you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no switch cases in Python. Even if there was, it would look more or less the same. One thing you can do is create a dictionary, and then just call dictionary[locatorStrategy] to get your function

Answer (score 0):

although there is no switch-case feature in python you can use a class to make one like this
    class PythonSwitch:

```
    def switch(self, timezone):
        default = "unknown timezone"
        return getattr(self, 'case_' + str(timezone), lambda: default)()

    def case_UTC(self):
        return 0

    def case_BST(self):
        return 1

    def case_PDT(self):
        return -7

s = PythonSwitch()

print(s.switch(BST))
print(s.switch(UTC))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!